# how to disable specific portion of a checkbox input label?

Tags: html, css

I want to ask something about html and/or css.

I created a checkbox input and its label, whenever users click the label, the checkbox is ticked/unticked, but in the middle of the label I insert a link to show some pop-up modal, now the behaviour of the label is, whenever Users click that modal link, the checkbox is getting clicked and ticked/unticked as well, how do I make it so when Users click the link, the checkbox didn't get clicked too?

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="agree" formControlName="agree">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="agree">
                          I agree to give some of my <span class="info-button text-muted"><a (click)="showModal()">personal information</a></span> to the partner that i worked with.
                        </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="agree" formControlName="agree">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="agree">
                          I agree to give some of my <span class="info-button text-muted"><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="showModal()">personal information</a></span> to the partner that i worked with.
                        </label>
</div>
```

update your html (a tag) with adding javascript:void(0) :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="showModal()">personal information</a>
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

to stop 'clck' event to bubble.